# Point to button to put add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

On the bottom of the site, there are radio buttons, which shows projects, these radio buttons are created everytime I add a project with this code:

```
<div id="menu">
     <a class="active" href="javascript:menuAction(0)"></a>
     <? $index = 0; foreach ($projects as $value) { $index++; echo '<a href="javascript:menuAction('.$index.')"></a>'; } ?>
</div>
```

The thing is that I want to put over some specific projects this "new dialog" icon under it´s radio button:

[image]

How can I point to a project radio button, to create a class and show the icon under it´s radio button? It would be a dialog.png image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code that adds the radio buttons, you need to determine if each button is 'new' or not.  For the new ones, add a 'newProject' class.

You can then use CSS to set the 'new' png graphic as a background image (or use the :after selector to insert a new element to hold the graphic)